# Using Master Document for report generation in Enterprise Architect V11 - store configuration and filters

Tags: reporting, enterprise-architect

fellows!

I have a problem with report generation from my model using a Master Document defining a complex documentation. I believe some of you can help me solve the problem.

---

**Facts:**

- I have a complex project consisting of several views and packages, inluding domain model, use case model, business process model, etc.
- The model is stored in shared (database) repository along with other projects.
- I have created custom templates, TOC, cover page and stylesheets for the documentation.
- I have created a Master Document package with the main template assigned defining the main document I want to have generated.
- I have created several Model Document elements in that package to define individual chapters of the document, assigning adequate templates and model packages to each of them.
- I have successfully generated the desired documentation.
- I am using Enterprise Architect version 11.0.1107

**Problem 1:**

I would like to have generated several variants of the same documentation. Thus, I need to change the settings of the generation process like the options, exclude filters and element filters.

However, the settings is not remembered after the generation and I have to set all the settings again when generating documentation on the Master Document package.

Is there a way to save the settings for the Master Document? I have found the Report Specification element, but it does not work as expected (see Problem 2).

**Problem 2:**

I have tried to use Report Specification element to save the settings for the report generation. I have created that element in the same package as the Master Document is located, and also inside of that Master Document package.

In both cases, when generating the documentation for the first time, EA asked me to select the package. I selected the Master Document package and confirmed the generation. However, the generated document is empty as it clearly does not take the Model Document elements in the selected package into account.

Did I use the Report Specification incorectly? Should I use another package for the Report Specification element? Should I select another package when using the Report Specification for report generation?

**Problem 3:**

I tried to apply element filters and some other options to include only some of the elements in the report. Let's say I want only element with the version 1.1. So I set the filters to "version = 1.1" when generating the report from the Master Document package.

However, the report contained all elements, regardless their version. The same happened when I tried to exclude anonymous elements. Furthermore, for the next try the filter settings was lost again and I had to set it again before next generation (see Problem 1).

Where should I configure the filters? Should it be set when generating using the Master Document package? Should it be set somewhere for the Model Document elements? Should it be set in the templates (thus making them very specific rather than general)? In such case, should it be set for the model template or for the individual fragments?

**Summary:**

If you have any tips for combination of Master Document and Report Specification, as well as using the element filters when generating from the Master Document, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

We do'nt use Report Specification element, but we store specific options into Resource Document. Use `[Resource Document]` button on Generate Documentation dialog. This specification is stored between Resources (see Resources Window) under Document Generation -> Defined Documents.I hope this solves problem 1 and 2

Problem 3 - EA has more ways, how select elements for generation, unfortunatelly you can't combine them (as far as I know). I would try to define custom find filter and use it.

Comment: Thank you, Petr, for that tip. I have created the Resource Document and it remembers the configuration. Unfortunatelly, it cannot be edited later, only rewriten by a new Resource Document. But it is OK.

Comment: You can edit it - use Right click on your Defined document and Generate Document. Generate Documentatioc dialog appears. Change your settings and store it again by using button [Resource Document] - give the same name, you overwrite old settings

Comment: That is what I meant - you need to type the name and rewrite the Resource Document. I would rather use [save] button to save the configuration for existing Resource Document or remember it automatically when generating from existing Resource Document. But I do not find this as a big problem ;)